# nav-tabs doesn't works without adding empty <ul> tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with a bootstrap tab view. My code seems ok, but i need to add a `<ul></ul>` code before the `<ul class="nav-tabs">` class to put my code working fine. Why ?

Normally, the code should work without this adding code..

```
<div class="tabbable-line">

    <ul></ul> <!-- IF I do no put this line, tab doesn't work ! Why ? -->

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs " data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#needsUI" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"> Needs
                <span class="icon-basket"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="#offerInformationsUI" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"> Information
                <span class="icon-notebook"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="#customerUI" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"> Customer
                <span class="icon-user"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="#confirmUI" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"> Confirm
                <span class="icon-check"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">


        <div class="tab-pane active" id="needsUI"></div>


        <div class="tab-pane" id="offerInformationsUI"></div>


        <div class="tab-pane" id="customerUI"></div>


        <div class="tab-pane" id="confirmUI"></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It works fine without the extra ul on my comp.

Comment: it works fine for me - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qNGRmW

Comment: Is there some javascript code that you run? put it in the question...

Comment: I need to check my js code so..

Comment: In fact, when my app is loaded, i add dynamically content in each div of tab-content. Could it be the source of the problem ?

Comment: What's your OUTPUTTED code?

Answer (score 0):

can you add this code

```
<ul>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

if work then ok or can you give me source code or test url?